# oAuth support in a WebView

Tags: android, oauth, webview

So I've created a simple WebView application that wraps an already existing mobile friendly site and displays it on the device. I've enabled javascript, supported screen orientation changes, etc... 
I've run into an issue with the oAuth support though. Accessing the site from the chrome browser on the device, everything runs fine. 
If I try to access the site from the app/WebView, it will push me over to the oAuth screen, let me input credentials and everything, but the moment it tries to push me back to the website and log me in, I get this:

```
Failed to recognize URL query:
https://exittix.com/frontend/login/redirect.html#access_token=******************************&expires_in=********&state=****client_id=******************network*****facebook*****display***popup****callback****_hellojs_agj27sx5****state****oauth_proxy***https***auth-server.herokuapp.com%2Fproxy***scope***basic_profile***email***basic***oauth***version***auth***https***facebook.com%2Foauth***
```

The `*` is used to protect data.

So, any ideas why oAuth isn't working inside a JS enabled webview but works fine in the mobile chrome browser for android?

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT:
Ok, so I've tracked the error I'm getting back to redirect.html.
This page calls some javascript. If the javascript fails to redirect, then it displays that error I have above instead.
The javascript being called to handle the oAuth is Andrew Dodson's hello.js script.
You can see it [HERE](http://adodson.com/hello.js/#quick-start).
I've concluded that the second half of the error's url is indeed the unhandled JSON.
Here's what the returned data looks like after I've decoded it from the URL encoded characters:

```
{"client_id":"************.apps.googleusercontent.com","network":"google","display":"popup","callback":"_hellojs_********","state":"","oauth_proxy":"https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/proxy","scope":["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email","basic"],"oauth":{"version":2,"auth":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"}}&access_token=***.*.*****_*********************************************************&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600
```

Any ideas why this isn't getting handled properly in the WebView?

Comment: Do you build this URL manually?
&state=****client_id=******************network*****facebook*****...
I see that you are missing the '&' symbol before "client_id". Are "netword" and "facebook" another query parameters?

Comment: I'm not handling the oAuth myself. That's handled by the webdev guys. The oAuth **works** with mobile browsers, laptops, etc... It's only in the WebView that it returns this error...

Comment: The funny thing is, Javascript is working fine because that error message is generated dynamically using javascript. If javascript just wasn't working, I would be getting a 404 error or something. Instead, I'm getting this error FROM javascript. It's failing because hello.js isn't redirecting or handling the JSON correctly. Why does that happen with the WebView but not the browser?